# Query regarding semantics about CompletableFuture?

Tags: java, multithreading, asynchronous, coding-style, completable-future

I have a question regarding CompletableFutures in java 8.

Semantically speaking the recipient of `CompletableFuture` should not invoke `complete` or `completeExceptionally`.

So why are the methods provided to the recipient of `CompletableFuture`. Is it that it's too complex to codify these semantics in the object or is there some other reason ? Or what I am assuming is completely wrong and its semantically correct for the recipient to call `complete` and `completeExceptionally`

Note:
I am not asking for use cases or if its possible in java 8, I want to understand what is semantically correct and why/why not that logic is codified in the `CompletableFuture` object

Comment: The complete\* methods ignore any executing task and override the result.  They are probably most useful when called on a CompletableFuture that has other tasks depending on its outcome.  Personally I have never yet found a good use for those methods.

Comment: A future is like a promise. So, conceptually, it's the one that made the promise that will either keep it or break it.

Comment: i understand what should be done semantically, but why isn't the semantics codified in the api ? Why is CompletableFuture written in such a way that anyone including the recipient of future can complete(success or failure) the said future. Is not possible to codify this ? cancel method completes the future exceptionally so how is it that calling cancel by the recipient semantically correct ?

Comment: The `CompletableFuture` can be completed because that’s what it is all about. That’s even indicated by its name. Apparently, a lot of developers overlook this trait because there are so many methods from the `CompletionStage` it implements, despite it is so present in its name. If you do not want the caller to complete it, use `CompletionStage` as return type. If you want to make it even safe against callers trying to cast it back to `CompletableFuture`, you can use `minimalCompletionStage()` in Java 9 or newer.

Comment: Hey @agent47 , I tried to make the question a bit more clear but it appears it doesn't quite hit what you're truly asking. I suggest you rephrase the question to ask why semantics can't be codified, and the completeable future ones in specific.